# ansible distribute elements from one list of dicts to different files

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have one list of dicts ( variable ):

```
sites:
  - { site: "https://site1.com", project: "own", module: "2xx" }
  - { site: "https://site2.com", project: "external", module: "2xx" }
  - { site: "https://site3.net", project: "own", module: "ssl" }
  - { site: "https://site4.org", project: "external", module: "ssl2" }
  - { site: "https://site5.co", project: "external", module: "2xx"}
```

simple template:

```
{% for dict_item in sites %}
 - targets:
   - {{ dict_item.site }}
  labels:
   instance: {{ dict_item.site }}
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: {{ dict_item.project }}
   module: {{ dict_item.module }}
{% endfor %}
```

and task :

```
- name: "Test multi"
  template:
    src: "test.yml.j2"
    dest: "/opt/test/{{ item.module }}.yml"
  with_items: "{{ sites }}"
```

So, with that task I'm trying to generate separate files ( {{ module}}.yml ) with own set of targets, based on "module" key. But unfortunately inside each of file I have whole list of targets.

What I have:

```
[root@localhost test]# cat 2xx.yml
 - targets:
   - https://site1.com
  labels:
   instance: https://site1.com
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: own
   module: 2xx
 - targets:
   - https://site2.com
  labels:
   instance: https://site2.com
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: external
   module: 2xx
 - targets:
   - https://site3.net
  labels:
   instance: https://site3.net
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: own
   module: ssl
 - targets:
   - https://site4.org
  labels:
   instance: https://site4.org
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: external
   module: ssl2
 - targets:
   - https://site5.co
  labels:
   instance: https://site5.co
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: external
   module: 2xx
```

```
[root@localhost test]# diff -u 2xx.yml ssl.yml
[root@localhost test]#
[root@localhost test]# diff -u 2xx.yml ssl2.yml
[root@localhost test]#
```

So content within every file the same and has whole list of records. BUT I want to split it in this way:

```
[root@localhost test]# cat 2xx.yml
 - targets:
   - https://site1.com
  labels:
   instance: https://site1.com
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: own
   module: 2xx
 - targets:
   - https://site2.com
  labels:
   instance: https://site2.com
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: external
   module: 2xx
 - targets:
   - https://site5.co
  labels:
   instance: https://site5.co
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: external
   module: 2xx

[root@localhost test]# cat ssl.yml
 - targets:
   - https://site3.net
  labels:
   instance: https://site3.net
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: own
   module: ssl

[root@localhost test]# cat ssl2.yml
 - targets:
   - https://site4.org
  labels:
   instance: https://site4.org
   job: "blackbox_exporter | sites_check"
   project: external
   module: ssl2
```

How I can differentiate targets by files ?

How I can differentiate targets by files ? I know that I can add different tasks for each of "module key" and filter it by "when" construction, but in the future I could have lots of modules and save DRY inside my roles tasks

Comment: The module `2xx` repeats three times in the *sites*. Do you really want to overwrite the file `/opt/test/{{ item.module }}.yml` three times?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer! Your resolution works, but I want to save inside one file several records with the same "module" label ( group records from the list to separate files by the "module" label ).

Comment: Good to know. Provide the expected results of these files. [edit] your question and make it [mre]. Your question will be closed if you don't provide a minimal, repeatable example.

Comment: I've tried to do my best with editor :)

Comment: I updated the answer. Fit the structure to your needs. Do you really need the lists? Wouldn't dictionaries do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: ***"Generate separate files {{ module }}.yml"***

A: For example, given the simplified list

```yaml
  sites:
    - {site: https://site1.com, project: own, module: 2xx}
    - {site: https://site2.com, project: external, module: 2xx}
    - {site: https://site3.net, project: own, module: ssl}
    - {site: https://site4.org, project: external, module: ssl2}
    - {site: https://site5.co, project: external, module: 2xx}
```

Write the files

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/test/{{ item.0 }}.yml"
        content: |
          {% for s in item.1 %}
          {{ s.site }}:
            instance: {{ s.site }}
            project: {{ s.project }}
            module: {{ s.module }}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ sites|groupby('module') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0 }}"
```

This will create the files

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── 2xx.yml
├── ssl2.yml
└── ssl.yml

0 directories, 3 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test/2xx.yml 
https://site1.com:
  instance: https://site1.com
  project: own
  module: 2xx
https://site2.com:
  instance: https://site2.com
  project: external
  module: 2xx
https://site5.co:
  instance: https://site5.co
  project: external
  module: 2xx
```

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test/ssl2.yml 
https://site4.org:
  instance: https://site4.org
  project: external
  module: ssl2
```

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test/ssl.yml 
https://site3.net:
  instance: https://site3.net
  project: own
  module: SSL
```

Use the module [*assemble*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assemble_module.html#ansible-builtin-assemble-module-assemble-configuration-files-from-fragments) if you want to put them together

```yaml
    - assemble:
        src: /tmp/test
        dest: /tmp/test/all.yml
```

This will create the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test/all.yml 
https://site1.com:
  instance: https://site1.com
  project: own
  module: 2xx
https://site2.com:
  instance: https://site2.com
  project: external
  module: 2xx
https://site5.co:
  instance: https://site5.co
  project: external
  module: 2xx
https://site3.net:
  instance: https://site3.net
  project: own
  module: ssl
https://site4.org:
  instance: https://site4.org
  project: external
  module: ssl2
```

You can read it and put it into a dictionary

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: /tmp/test/all.yml
        name: targets
```

gives

```yaml
  targets:
    https://site1.com:
      instance: https://site1.com
      module: 2xx
      project: own
    https://site2.com:
      instance: https://site2.com
      module: 2xx
      project: external
    https://site3.net:
      instance: https://site3.net
      module: ssl
      project: own
    https://site4.org:
      instance: https://site4.org
      module: ssl2
      project: external
    https://site5.co:
      instance: https://site5.co
      module: 2xx
      project: external
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    sites:
      - {site: https://site1.com, project: own, module: 2xx}
      - {site: https://site2.com, project: external, module: 2xx}
      - {site: https://site3.net, project: own, module: ssl}
      - {site: https://site4.org, project: external, module: ssl2}
      - {site: https://site5.co, project: external, module: 2xx}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sites|groupby('module') }}"
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/test/{{ item.0 }}.yml"
        content: |
          {% for s in item.1 %}
          {{ s.site }}:
            instance: {{ s.site }}
            project: {{ s.project }}
            module: {{ s.module }}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ sites|groupby('module') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0 }}"

    - assemble:
        src: /tmp/test
        dest: /tmp/test/all.yml

    - include_vars:
        file: /tmp/test/all.yml
        name: targets

    - debug:
        var: targets
```